# How to set a tensorflow variable to the first input data?

Tags: variables, tensorflow, initialization

Is it possible to set a tensorflow variable to the first value of the input data inside a method?

Suppose that we have input data like x[0], x[1], ... x[N-1].
I would like to make a tensorflow variable store the first "x[0]" value inside a Python method. The following is a simplified code:

```
def Graph(placeholder):
    # I want to store the first value of placeholder in "u"
    u = tf.get_variable('x', dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)


    # Some calculation including 'u'
    # For example, y = 0.7 * placeholder - u

    return y
```

Is it ever possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Here `placeholder[:1]` is slicing syntax to get the first value which is `1`

`u = u.assign(placeholder[:1])` is the assignment of the first element.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

placeholder = tf.placeholder( tf.int32, shape=(4,))

def Graph(placeholder):

    # I want to store the first value of placeholder in "u"
    with tf.variable_scope("reuse", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

        u = tf.get_variable('x',[1],dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)

        u = u.assign(placeholder[:1])

        place_print = tf.Print(placeholder[:1],[placeholder[:1]])
        u_print = tf.Print(u,[u])

        # Some calculation including 'u'
        y = 7 * place_print - u_print

        return y

with tf.Session() as sess:

    with tf.variable_scope("reuse", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

        u = tf.get_variable("x", [1], dtype=tf.int32)

        f = Graph(placeholder)

        sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )

        print(sess.run( [f,u],feed_dict={placeholder: [1, 2, 3, 4]}))
```

Output is

```
[array([6]), array([0])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case, the issue is that placeholder will not contain the whole training data, and each one will be given separately. I will somewhat update my question tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Your next question is new. I think.